# R: Get the min/max of each item of a vector compared to single value

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I want to compare a single value with each item of a vector (data.frame column) and receive a new vector as result.

```
a <- data.frame(v=c(3,1,5))
n <- 4
b <- # get max of `a$v` and `n` and return a vector
#desired output:
#[1] 4 4 5
```

The normal `max` function does not work.

Comment: How about `ifelse(a$v >= n, a$v, n)`?

Comment: Thx, for the comment. This was helpful and helped me to replace Inf/0 values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for `pmin`/`pmax`:

```
> pmin(a$v, n)
[1] 3 1 4
> pmax(a$v, n)
[1] 4 4 5
```